# How to access another database dynamically in same instance in SQL Server side?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases at same instance with below names:

```
SaleTabriz1394
SaleTabrizArchive
```

I want to access to **SaleTabrizArchive** via **SaleTabriz1394** to access archive information.
I don't want to uses such code in Main database : **SaleTabrizArchive.dbo.SampleTable**

Is there any solution to access to **SaleTabrizArchive** dynamically without writing its name in **SaleTabriz1394** ?

> **SaleTabriz1394** : Current Financial Year database
>
> **SaleTabrizArchive** : Older Financial Year information database
>
> **Note :** I should add this note that I want to do use **table valued function** that doesn't support **dynamic
>   query**. so using dynamic query is not my answer.

for example I entered SaleTabrizArchive name in Special Table in SaleTabriz1394 and we can access to Archive database through that. but using dynamic query is not my goal.

Comment: What is *real* problem you're trying to solve? Accessing database without specifying its name looks like pretty syntetic goal.  Where exactly sql server should search for data if you're not pointing to it?

Comment: No I mean I want to access that database dynamically without writing its name manually in my SaleTabriz1394 queries. is there any solution?

Comment: Well, accoring to your question - you can't use dynamic sql in your particular case. So you have no other options....

Comment: so in this issue I think SQL server has a defect.

Comment: No it doesn't have a defect - you have imposed constraints making your requirements impossible. But anyway it appears you are really after _table partitioning_. If you explain your real issue further (i.e. why you are spreading data across databases) we might be able to suggest further.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamically? can you show a scenario where you need to select or manipulate data that you don't know in which database it exists?

Comment: Tbh it seems to me he can't be bothered to change all procedures / stuffs in new DB to aim for old DB when it's needed ... But your request kinda seems impossible ... "Go bring me milk from specific store and I can't tell you location of it"

Comment: If table names do not change in real time, then use synonyms.

Comment: ah yes synonyms are a good idea. But I assume they are making the classic mistake of archiving off into another database to 'improve' performance when there are any number of better ways to achieve this.